# Looking for user-friendly project reporting tool for coordination

Tags: project-management

I'm looking for an online reporting tool/software that would allow people in different countries to submit information on the advancement of a project (defined by very precise criteria), every two weeks. The page could look like a word document or an excel file (information divided into boxes/headings...).

What I'm hoping to find:

- as the coordinator, I can see what everyone wrote, but reporters can't see what other people wrote
- all the data entered goes into a single document
- Ideally, the software is open-source
- Can be used on windows

I have tried smartsheet but the web form is tedious for the people reporting.

My apologies for not using the appropriate terms, I am not familiar with those kinds of software and English is not my first language.

Thank you so much for your help.